# jQuery - Separate text into strings

Tags: jquery, loops

Lets say my HTML looks like this:

```
<p>12345, 23, 64229, 359</p>
```

This paragraph can have hundreds of values separated by comma.
It can also be empty.

I wanna make these values into links.
The first value should link to "http://www.example.com/?id=12345"
The second value to "http://www.example.com/?id=23"
..and so on.

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex `.replace()`, something like this:

```
​$("p").html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/\d+/g, function(m) { return "http://www.example.com/?id=" + m; });
});​​
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/M8fne/), or to make them clickable links:

```
$("p").html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/\d+/g, function(m) { 
     return "<a href='http://www.example.com/?id="+m+"'>"+m+"</a>"; 
  });
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/M8fne/1/).

Answer (score 1):

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/uJRb6/

```
var nums = $('p').text().split(/\s*,\s*/);
var tags = '';

    $.each(nums,function(i,val) {
        tags += '<a href=http://www.example.com/?id=' + val + '>' + val + '</a><br>'
    });
$('body').append(tags);​
```

If you're concerned about the security of the content, you could do this:

```
var nums = $('p').text().split(/\s*,\s*/);
var tags = [];

    $.each(nums,function(i,val) {
        tags.push($('<a>',{text:val + ' ', href:'http://www.example.com/?id=' + val}));
    });
$(tags).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need jQuery for this, you can mostly do this with pure javascript:

```
vals = $('p').html().split(',');
for(var i in vals) {
  tags += '<a href=http://www.example.com/?id=' + val + '>link</a><br>'
}
$('body').append(tags)
```

Comment: Not to be difficult, but aside from the string appending, this *is* mostly jQuery :)

Comment: `for/in` over an Array is not a good idea. You should use a `for` loop.